# Magic method toString PHP

Tags: php, tostring, magic-methods

If i create two classes in one php file, and define the magic method __toString() for both,which one of them will be executed?Because i have already done this and one of them is executed...i just don't know why?

```
public function __toString(){
    return $this->pla_id." Nom = ".$this->pla_nom.", Rayon = ".$this->pla_rayon.", Gravitation = ".$this->pla_gravitation;
}

public function __toString(){
        return $this->sat_id."  ".$this->sat_nom."  ".$this->sat_rayon." ".$this->sat_rotation;
    }
```

and in another file:

```
$mars = new Planete(); $mars->setNom("Mars"); $mars->setRayon(3397); 
$mars->setGravitation(3.69);
$ph = new Satellite(); $ph->setNom("Phobos"); 
$ph->setPlanete($mars->getNom()); $ph->setRotation(0.32);
echo $mars;
```

but only the first one appears!

Comment: also try `echo $ph;` to see function overriding magic.

Comment: i know i forgot about it! but how can i show the variables like(name,age...) of the two classes with one tostring?

Comment: call `parent::__toString();` in child class's `__toString` method.

Comment: `public function __toString(){ $str = parent::__toString();
        return $str.'\n'.$this->sat_id."  ".$this->sat_nom."  ".$this->sat_rayon." ".$this->sat_rotation;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to echo the other class instance, my fault!
the answer is to add echo $ph in the last code sorry!!